# Git Clone Works, but Fetch Fails with ssh config'ed Host

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-config

I can clone my repo from github using ssh, but can't fetch or push.  I'm using an ssh config with a host entry, named gh-personal, that points to github.com and provides my pubkey.

Furthermore, the usual debugging technique, setting GIT_SSH_COMMAND to "ssh -v," causes the fetches and pushes to WORK.

The clone works:

```
$ git clone git@gh-personal:dgentry/myDotfiles 
Cloning into 'myDotfiles'...
remote: Enumerating objects: . . . .
Resolving deltas: 100% (3570/3570), done.
```

The fetch immediately after fails:

```
$ cd myDotfiles/
$ git fetch
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gh-personal: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Set GIT_SSH_COMMAND in an attempt at debugging, and it works:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh" git fetch
$ # This works
```

All I can figure is that git is using some kind of internal ssh by default, and *that* ssh isn't looking up my .ssh/config entry for gh-personal.

(There's more weirdness.  If I clone the repo into a directory whose name doesn't match the repo name, fetch/push works normally.)

And, for reference, here's the ~/.ssh/config entry for gh-personal:

```
Host gh-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Does anyone know how to make this work always?

Comment: Consider setting `core.sshCommand` (with `git config --global`), but yeah, it's weird that `git clone` would work at all then. Also consider running with whatever system-call-tracing facility you have, which may help you find out which ssh Git is actually running each time.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any environment variable related to SSH, by typing `set`.
And if your `PATH` references the another `ssh` before the Git one.

Note the URL can be `gh-personal:dgentry/myDotfiles`, no need for `git@`, since the `User` is part of your `gh-personal` entry in your ~/.ssh/config.

To be safe, make sure you are testing this with the latest Git version you can upgrade to.

Comment: Yes, no SSH env vars, just the .ssh/config.  And PATH has only the one ssh, same priority as git:  
```$ which git; which ssh``` produces
```/usr/bin/git
/usr/bin/ssh```

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about the URL -- I use that all the time now.

Comment: @SomeGuyontheInternet Do you still have the issue? What version of Git are you using? On which OS? Is it a git bash session on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I never got this working the way I expect, but it's working well enough either just leaving GIT_SSH_COMMAND set, or using @torek's suggestion they made in a comment.  This is on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 with the latest ubuntu git packages.  I'll give git bash on Windows a try too.